# wordpress form - submit data to post using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an idea, and I'm wondering if it is doable. I want to have a WordPress form that you can put your email into, and then it will send that email to a custom `post` for subscribers. I've read a few WordPress pages that utilize Ajax, and they require 'nonce' or a unique user ID. Can anyone help me figure out how to do this?

Comment: Yes its possible, please post the code that you have by now so we can help you.

Comment: You can try to do it with wp ajax api I dont think it will require nonce nor a logged in user -> https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)

Comment: Please check this document before post you code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve